# Rails link_to update attribute from controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, update-attributes

I want to be able to have a link that when pressed updates one attribute based up a controller action. How would I be able to do this? Do I have to create a separate update route? I am new at this so please bear with me.

controller

```
def completed
 @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
 if @meeting.day_of_meeting == @meeting.days
  @meeting.update_attribute(:day_of_meeting, '1')
  redirect_to :back
 else
  @meeting.increment!
  redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

model

```
def increment!
  update_attribute(:day_of_meeting, day_of_meeting + 1)
end
```

view

```
<%= link_to meetings_completed_path(@meeting), remote: true do %>
```

routes

```
resources :meetings do
  get 'meetings/completed'
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

1. Since you are updating a record you need to include `method: :patch` in your link and also you need to modify the routes file to include appropriate route.

   In your routes file add

   ```
   #routes.rb
   resources :meetings do
     member do
       patch 'completed'
     end
   end
   ```

   In your view

   ```
   <%= link_to "Mark as completed", completed_meeting_path(@meeting), remote: true, method: :patch  %>
   ```
2. Since you have a `remote:true` in your link so rails will try to render a javascript template and since you are not rendering a javascript template you will get a template missing error

   In your controller

   ```
   def completed
     @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
       # if something ...
         # update meeting record and then render js template
         format.js {render :status => :ok} # it will render completed.js.erb inside 'app/views/meetings/' directory
       # else
         # something else
         format.js {render :action => "different_action"} # it will render different_action.js.erb inside 'app/views/meetings/' directory 
     end
   end
   ```

Now all you need to do is to write some basic javascript in the js templates to update the view.

Note : If you don't want to render anything simply use `format.js { render :nothing => true }`.
Also if you want to use `redirect_to` calls instead of rendering js template just remove `remote: true` form you link .

Comment: thank you for clearing that up. I have one other question. Is it correct to write if meeting.day_of_meeting == meeting.days when trying to determine if two values equal the same?

Comment: First i am not sure about what you are trying to do but considering meeting.day_of_meeting and meeting.days return timestamp values like "Tue, 17 Jun 2014 18:52:25 UTC +00:00" you should use rails to_date method which will give you a date from a timestamp like "Tue, 17 Jun 2014" then you can compare whether two dates are same like  meeting.day_of_meeting.to_date === meeting.days.to_date .

Comment: Also its a bad idea to store integer values to day_of_meeting field while you should be storing a timestamp value. Then you can do something like @meeting.day_of_meeting+1.day  but it depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

You can set the action in set_member_album =: image_capa

```
#app/controllers/member/albums_controller.rb
class Member::AlbumsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_member_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :image_capa]

  #PATCH/PUT /adm/image_capa/1
  def image_capa
    # @member_album = Member::Album.find(params[:id]) # sempre colocar a action before_action :set_member_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :image_capa]
    if @member_album.update(image_capa: params[:image_capa])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to member_albums_url, notice: t('albums.image_capa_success') }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_member_album
      @member_album = Member::Album.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```